# Remember the last selected tab with localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

In a bootstrap 4 website, I have the tabs below:

```
<ul id="tabsJustified" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab1" data-target="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">Personal details</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab2" data-target="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Medical conditions</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab3" data-target="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Medication</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab4" data-target="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Care needs</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab4" data-target="#tab5" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">Care environment</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tab3" data-target="#tab6" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle mr-2"></i>Add a second client</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want is, remember the last selected tab and when the page reloads, go to that tab.

With this code, it's only working with the 1st, 2nd and 6th tab.

```
$(function() { 
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
    });
    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    if (lastTab) {
        $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
        console.log(lastTab);
    }
});
```

When I click the 4th tab, after reload, the 5th tab will be active.
The `console.log` row gives back the correct tab id or href, I checked that.

Comment: The `href` value of the sixth tab should be `#tab6`. Same as the fifth `#tab5`.

Comment: All `href` values should be unique, the last two aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, check your `href` values, you have incorrect increment "1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3", because you have "4" twice, that is why fifth is selected.

Just change it to "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks! I didnt see it :)